# Is it possible to use flash encryption in esp32 in Arduino ide

Tags: esp32-cam

Just already finished writing the program in arduino ide, but were just thinking if i could use flash encryption in esp32 using arduino ide for commercial use? Cause i am still new to this esp-idf stuffs and wondering if i could set some security config using arduino ide.